# Cocoa QTMovieView keydown not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, osx-lion, quicktime

I have a QTMovieView control on my cocoa window and it's working great with movies.

Now I want to intercept key down / up events to control the video as I like.

I created a MyMovieView class derived from QTMovieView like this

```
@interface MyMovieView : QTMovieView

-(BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder;
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent;

@end
```

and the code that implements it.

I tried to insert the class name "MyMovieView" into the "Custom Class" field of the Interface Builder inspector for the control QTMovieView but seems like after I close the interface builder, the class gets lost and the "Custom Class" field doesn't remember MyMovieView class.

Am I getting something wrong with the subclass mechanism? I'm a Cocoa newbie

Comment: A few question, which version of XCode are you using.  Did you save your nib before closing interface builder ?

Comment: Yes I did, I think I have Xcode 4.2

Comment: I took that code and shove it in a basic xcode project with just an NSLog when the keysDown method is called which logs the key that wash pushed.  I might add that depending on your setup, you might need to click on your qtView.  Here is a url you can test   [link](http://crypto.cs.mcgill.ca/~simonpie/Divers/TestAppPourLePlaisir.zip) my small project.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it as soon as I get home (5 days)

Comment: @simonpie : please add your comment as an answer, your solution worked and I want to add points to your kindness.

Comment: i deleted the app delegate... i know.. i'm stupid :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, I took it and shove it in a basic Xcode project with just an NSLog in the keyDown method which logs the key that was pushed.  Here is a link to the the [Project](http://crypto.cs.mcgill.ca/~simonpie/Divers/TestAppPourLePlaisir.zip).